Locating volume 2 of certain conference proceedings in analytic number theory
Does anyone know where one might locate "Analytic Number Theory: Proceedings of a Conference in Honor of Heini Halberstam, Volume 2"? There exists Volume 1 here: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4086-0, though I am unable to locate the second volume anywhere.

Volume 2 is in the same series (Progress in Mathematics 139) as Volume 1 (Progress in Mathematics 138). Birkhauser, ISBN: 9780817639334. See, eg., https://www.allbookstores.com/Analytic-Number-Theory-The-Halberstam/9780817639334

Hi Mayank, I sent you a relevant email.
